# I am Trying to center the card but its not working

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am building a react application in which I am trying to center the blocks,by using justify content center but its not working. I have used the justify-content-center, center -block ,but still its not working

Please Help me out

```
function Trackers(props) {

  return (
    <>
      
      <h2 class="font-weight-bold text-center mt-4 mb-4" >COVID-19 TRACKER</h2>
      <Container>
        <Row >
        <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={4} className="center-block">
      
          <Card style={{ width: '15rem' }} className="justify-content-center text-center ml-1 mr-1 mt-1 mb-1" >
            <Card.Body>
              <h6>Infected</h6>
              <h5>{props.data["statewise"][0]["active"]}</h5>
              <br />
              <h6>No of Active Cases of Covid-19</h6>
              <Container className="bg-primary " style={{height:"5px" ,width:"auto"}} height="20px" width="auto"  >

              </Container>

            </Card.Body>
          </Card></Col>

          
          <Col xs={12}  sm={12} md={4} className="justify-content-center ">
      
          <Card style={{ width: '15rem' }} className="text-center ml-1 mr-1 mt-1 mb-1" >
            <Card.Body>
              <h6>Recovered</h6>
              <h5>{props.data["statewise"][0]["recovered"]}</h5>
              <br />
              <h6>No of Recovered Cases of Covid-19</h6>
              <Container className="bg-success " style={{height:"5px" ,width:"auto"}} height="20px" width="auto"  >

              </Container>

            </Card.Body>
          </Card></Col>
          <Col xs={12}  sm={12} md={4} className="justify-content-center ">
       
        <Card style={{ width: '15rem' }} className="text-center ml-1 mr-1 mt-1 mb-1">
            <Card.Body>
              <h6>Deaths</h6>
              <h5>{props.data["statewise"][0]["deaths"]}</h5>
              <br />
              <h6>No of Deaths Cases of Covid-19</h6>
              <Container className="bg-dark " style={{height:"5px" ,width:"auto"}} height="20px" width="auto"  >

              </Container>
 
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
         </Col>       
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqKYV.png

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add class `p-0`(zero padding) to your `Col` and then on your `Card` element replace classes `ml-1 mr-1` with just `mx-auto` (sets the margins on the x-axis, left & right to auto)

https://jsfiddle.net/85nj7tz1/

FYI `.justify-content-center` is used on a row to center the columns within the row.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer you already have with `mx-auto`.
On top of that you can also introduce `h-100` on the cards to make them align properly on all screens. With a `.card-footer` you can align the border layout as well.

[DEMO with columns](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/co40ryva/)

To take it a little further, you can get rid of the columns and use a card-layout.
A `.card-deck` seems the ideal approach.

[DEMO with card-layout](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/dLpohgcj/)